How to know status of a component?
If a part is NFND (not for new design) on for example in Octopart but active in Avnet, Digikey and Mouser, how am I suppose to know what is up?
Can I use this part or not? I mailed the manufacturer but no answer so far.
It is already on a board that is currently manufactured.
Does anyone know where else I can check for the status? Or is the only way forward hoping the manufacturer answers?

it is already on a board that is currently manufactured Are you looking for post-mortem support on a product you've already shipped or are you currently in production and you found out that the part is now NFND? Either way, I feel like the manufacturer or the distributor should have already provided a heads up well in advance.


How am I suppose to know what is up?

You will have to ask the party you trust. If in doubt, this would be the manufacturer of the part.
But there's also good reason to stick your distributor – they might have their own reasons to declare something "not recommended", for example planning to drop the manufacturer's products from their supply chain. Switching distributors for a single part might be more effort or cost than switching components.

or the only way forward is hoping the manufacturer answers?

If a manufacturer is asked "Hey, distributor XYZ tells me your device is NRND, and I haven't found anything about that on your website, what is your recommended action?", then you have a problem with manufacturer trustworthiness anyways, and might be well-advised looking for other manufacturers, anyways. 
If they don't answer to this very simple and crucial inquiry, yes, you will need to find a  different manufacturer.

The manufacturer is the place to look for this kind if information. And every reputable manufacturer should happily give you that information either directly on their website or through other communication channels.
I don't know how the distributors get this information. Optimally they use an API from the manufacturer and get the status in real time. The other extreme would be a poor intern checking the part status manually every once and a while.

I would imagine authorized distributors get notified by the manufacturer when part status changes. Octopart, which aggregates information from multiple distributors, probably relies on getting data from the distributors it gets data from, which includes unauthorized distributors and may be wrong. So I would trust the authorized distributors over Octopart.

Seconding what @Hearth said: You can typically register with the manufacturer for part updates, and the "job" of a distributor includes keeping on top of what needs and can be stocked, and at which time, so they do.

Oftentimes if a part is going to be entirely discontinued by a manufacturer, they inform their distributors that there is a window available for a "Last time buy," where they will fulfill that PO, but none thereafter. I agree with comments above that the mfr's inside customer service should be able to tell you about a component's status, but you could survey Avnet, Digikey and Mouser too. The NFND status could also mean that an improved version of that part is about to be released, in which case you might not have anything to worry about.
